# How I can convert the relation between two terms in Coq

Tags: coq

I have less than relationship between two terms (S i2) < i1. May I write it in the form of less or equal (a1<=a2).

Answer (score 0):

You can `Search` for relevant lemmas:

```
Require Import Arith.

Search (_ < _) (_ <= _).
```

If you wish to preserve the same information, you have two options:

1. Do a case analysis on `i1`:

   1.1. if it's `0` then you have an impossible statement, since there is no natural number smaller than zero. To look for this fact, `Search (_ < 0)` provides `Nat.nlt_0_r`.

   1.2. if it's a successor, say `S i1'`, then your statement becomes `S i2 < S i1'`. From our `Search` above, we found `Nat.lt_succ_r`, so we can rewrite our `S i2 < S i1'` to `S i2 <= i1'`.
2. Use `Nat.lt_le_pred` directly, but this will lead to `S i2 <= Nat.pred i1`, and the predecessor of `i1` may or may not be useful to you.

Alternatively, if you know `S i2 < i1` but you only care that `S i2 <= i2`, ie, you want to *weaken* your hypothesis, you can use `Nat.lt_le_incl`.

Answer (score 0):

These terms are not fully equivalent, but the first is stronger than the second, using transitivity with the weakening `i2 <= S (S i2)` does suffice:

```
Require Import PArith PeanoNat.

Lemma example a b : S a < b -> a <= b.
Proof.
assert (a <= S (S a)).
  now apply Le.le_Sn_le, Le.le_Sn_le.
exact (Nat.le_trans _ _ _ H).
Qed.
```

Recall that `a < b` is notation for `S a <= b`. You can also just weaken directly in backwards-chaining style.

```
Lemma example2 a b : S a < b -> a <= b.
Proof. now intros hlt; apply Nat.lt_le_incl, Nat.lt_le_incl. Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for early stages of learning Coq, I would recommend the `lia` tactic:

```
Require Import PArith PeanoNat.
Require Import Lia.

Lemma example a b : S a < b -> a <= b.
Proof.
  intros H.
  lia.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you. By using which command I can convert  S a < b into  a <= S (S a) ?  Secondly in order to prove following what helping lemmas i should have  Theorem find_count: forall (s :list nat),
  leb (count 0 s) (count (S(0)) s) = true.

Comment: You need to be more precise in your questions. I don't know a function named `count`, so you would have to define it. The other question has a typo (two `a` in `a <= S (S a)`) and it is not obvious what exactly you want. I general I trust in `lia` - if it can't prove something about linear integer arithmetic, it is most likely wrong.